# Multiple Selections in a Combobox

Tags: if-statement, powerapps

I have a combobox that allows me to select more than one option, but I don't know how to test the value.  I can select Cat or Dog, and test it with an IF statement.  But how do I test for both Cat and Dog?

[image]

How would I test this in an IF statement?

Kindest,

Zorn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [PowerApps **And** function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-logicals) (equivalent to a logical AND operator) inside your [PowerApps **If** function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-if). For example:

`If(And(check for cat selected, check for dog selected), then-statement, else-statement)`